# Xcode 12.2 Crash. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7e4)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After I upgraded Xcode to version 12.2, the project had serious problems. EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashed frequently. When debugging, the console prompt:

```
-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x283e9e990.
```

The crashed string is a long string, similar to this:

```
 EBGUHMFDJNGGJMUFEHKJCIPNGICJEBBCCEBBJNEUFJOAHCLOJFPLNUECMHAADBKBBHMNLFMCHBALCACEOIBJUDGNEA
```

But it is normal in Xcode 11 or Xcode 10. Does Xcode 12.2 need to modify some configuration? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Any suggestions are very much appreciated,this problem has troubled me for many days.

Comment: Show what ```modeItem``` is. And where do you store that string? I guess modeItem.workmode but it matters a lot. Looks like that has been released by the time ```connectDeviceSuccess``` triggers.

Comment: @skaak Thanks for skaak's reply, I append my sample code.

Comment: Hi - in ```- connectDeviceSuccess``` you have ```XMConnectParameter parameter;``` and just after that you set ```parameter.serverString```. Shouldn't that be ```XMConnectParameter parameter = [[XMConnectParameter alloc] init];``` or similar? It seems that ```parameter``` will be ```nil``` by the time you set the ```serverString```?

Comment: Hi, `XMConnectParameter` is a `struct`,it cannot `alloc init`.

Comment: Ok thanks - difficult since I'm blind (to the code), difficult to help. Do you release anything yourself? Seems that is the problem? And do you know what that long string is? Is it e.g. parameter.serverString?

Comment: Hi, @skaak After discussing with you, I found the problem. The reason is this code in `connectDevice`: `self.parameter = parameter; `, `self.parameter` is `@property (nonatomic, assign) XMConnectParameter parameter; `. I guess Apple fixed the `assign` release logic after Xcode12, which caused my `serverString` to be released early.

Comment: Great - glad you solved it. Why not use ```@property (nonatomic,strong)``` ... but hey, if it works, don't change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the problem with my code, I found the problem. The reason is that `assign` will released the `serverString` in `struct XMConnectParameter` after Xcode12.

```
struct XMConnectParameter {
    NSString *serverString;
    NSInteger channel;
    // ...
};

typedef struct XMConnectParameter XMConnectParameter;

@property (nonatomic, assign) XMConnectParameter parameter;
```